# "Cyclic" conditional probability calculation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given random variables $x, y, z$, is there any useful interpretation of the quantity $p(x|y)p(y|z)p(z|x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have a useful *interpretation*, though what you're doing has a long history as an *approximation*.

It was introduced as a way to approximate the joint distribution $p(x, y, z)$ by [Besag (1974)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2984812). It's sometimes called the [pseudolikelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudolikelihood). Your particular expression also requires some conditional independence assumptions, but it works the same way; the pseudolikelihood is normally $p(x \mid y, z)p(y \mid z, x) p(z \mid x, y)$.

---

I first learned about this in an [extra credit problem](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Ejason/465/hw-prob/hw-prob.pdf) in Johns Hopkins University's natural language processing class. For the sake of students who take the class in the future, I won't go into details that might help them to answer that question.

Comment: Interesting!  I wonder what practical difference the additional conditions make.

If you look at entropies instead of at probabilities, things start looking an awful lot like (parts of) the trivariate mutual information...